# Module not detected in python3 but works in python2

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import, importerror

I installed a python package which has below dir structure.

```
pkg_name/
  __init__.py
  work.py
  helper.py
```

In work.py, an import is done as below -

```
from helper import MyClass
```

It works fine in python2.7 virtual env but gives below error in python3 venv

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'helper'

I modified the work.py import statement by adding "." as below and then it works fine in python3.

```
from .helper import MyClass
```

Question - Is there a way to make it run in python3 without modifying package files? (Or the package is published keeping just python2 in mind)

**EDIT: Adding __init__.py content below**

```
from .work import Sample
from .helper import MyClass
```

Comment: What is the difference between the two options you tried? Did you accidentally add a period in the first try that gives the error?

Comment: oops, I had a typo in my question. Now you can see the difference. When it was not working for python3 then I modified the downloaded package file (work.py) by adding a period to make it work. For python2 the package works just fine.

Comment: You haven't shared any info about the package so it's impossible to answer the question

Comment: @DavidSidarous Package is not from a public pypi repo. I gave the details of change I had to make in order to run it in python3. I will also add the content of __init.py__

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you run out of luck. The [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#package-relative-imports) of Python 3 states:

> Relative imports use leading dots. A single leading dot indicates a
>   relative import, starting with the current package. Two or more
>   leading dots indicate a relative import to the parent(s) of the
>   current package, one level per dot after the first.

For more information about this change, see this [PEP](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0328/#rationale-for-relative-imports) from almost 16 years ago.

I suggest to stop using Python 2 and get used to the Python 3 way of working.

Comment: Okay. If the owner of this package changes it as per python3 style then will it still work in python2? If not, then how to make such imports compatible with both python2 and python3?

Comment: I don't know to be honest whether this will work in Python 2. One way to be certain that it would work in both is to not use relative imports to begin with, so use `from pkg_name.helper import MyClass`.

Answer (score 1):

Whether you had `helper.py` in your python path would determine if you are able to import it directly or not.

And if you did not explicitly set PYTHONPATH, the directory from where you tried to run your script would get added to the PYTHONPATH.

Addendum:

If we are trying import something with a relative import:

```py
from .module import data
```

is adviced.

However, it is always better to provide the full path like this:

```py
from pkg_name.helper import MyClass
```

to avoid any ambiguity.

Comment: Thanks, This was helpful